# Solving quadratic congruence equation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, modulo

In order to solve

```
   x^2 == 123456 mod 1299709
```

in Mathematica I have used:

```
  Reduce[x^2 == 123456 + 1299709 k, {x, k}, Integers]
```

which yields the correct answer.

Question: Is **Reduce** the best way ( performance, elegance or otherwise ) to solve quadratic congruence equations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you are seeking the [`Modulus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Modulus.html) option.

```
Reduce[x^2 == 123456, x, Modulus -> 1299709]
```

```
(*Out[]=  x == 427784 || x == 871925 *)
```

Quoting the documentation:

> **Modulus -> n**
>   is an option that can be given in certain algebraic functions to specify that integers should be treated modulo n.
>
> - Equations for Modulus can be given in Solve and related functions.
> - Modulus appears as an option in Factor, PolynomialGCD and PolynomialLCM, as well as in linear algebra functions such as Inverse,
>     LinearSolve and Det.
> - Arithmetic is usually done over the full ring ℤ of integers; setting the option Modulus specifies that arithmetic should instead be
>     done in the finite ring ℤ<sub>n</sub>.
> - The setting Modulus->0 specifies the full ring ℤ of integers.
> - Some functions require that Modulus be set to a prime, or a power of a prime. ℤ<sub>n</sub> is a finite field when n is prime.

Comment: That is the elegance I was looking for. ;-)

Comment: @nilo :-)  I wasn't sure that was the answer you wanted, hence my wording.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Considering your edit, you clearly underestimated the response to your answer. - Beauty speaks in silence.

Comment: @Nilo, are you saying I should not have made that edit?  Sorry guys, I am more obtuse than usual today.

Answer (score 2):

```
In[1]:= PowerModList[123456, 1/2, 1299709]
Out[1]= {427784, 871925}
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: Now why did you have to post that and spoil the moment? ;-) +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "Sorry about that, Chief." (Of course there are always the other great Maxwell Smart remarks. I am reminded, for example of the classic "If only he'd used PowerModList for good, instead of evil". Okay, it's a slight paraphrase. So sue me.)

Comment: Daniel, now the I know you're a fan of agent 86, or at least some quotes, I'll be sure to drop some allusions from time to time. :D